# Sample code for adding annotation/note in Javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have an HTML file and I am opening it with Webkit.

I want to develop an app such that after opening it, I should be able to select some text and make it noted (say by pressing a 'Note Text' button).

When I press the button, a note image should appear on the right, but I cannot figure out the selected text position and I also have no idea about how to add a floating image on the right (maybe a div element)?

Can anyone give me a fragment of sample code about adding annotations/notes in Javascript?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Helping you is a lot easier when we can see what javascript/css/html you have already put together

Comment: In addition to what @Keith.Abramo said, have you tried googling `javascript selection position` and `javascript floating button`?

Answer (score 2):

I recently used [this](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/range_intro.html) article on Quirksmode.org to get started with identifying a user selection in Javascript. Essentially, IE differs from other browsers in what information you get about the selection: Mozilla and other browsers provide the relatively powerful [Selection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsISelection), while IE provides a [TextRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535872%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

If you're able to stick to Webkit-based browsers, you have significant ability to identify selected text with the Selection returned by `window.getSelection()`.

As for adding a floating image near your selected text, you can use the `anchorNode` property of the Selection to find the element near to which you'll want to add your image. To do the actual positioning of the image - yes, probably in a `div`, I recommend learning about [positioning in CSS](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/).